# Foreach works only with first item of ListBox

Tags: c#, foreach, listbox, windows-phone

My Windows Phone app has a ListBox populated from JSON. After I have the ListBox populated, I need to compare if what the user typed (string) exists in the ListBox.
So, each item on ListBox has 3 informations, from a collection. I need to compare only one item of the collection with the string.

I have some code, but this works only for the first item of ListBox:

```
private void addProduto(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{            
    Fields fi = (Fields)this.List1.SelectedItem as Fields;

    foreach(var item in List1.Items)
    {
        Fields fields = item as Fields;

        if (fields.codigo == insCodProduto.Text)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("this product exists!");
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("this product not exists");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Collection:

```
public ObservableCollection<Fields> Items { get; set; }

public class Fields
{
    public string descricao { get; set; }
    public double valor_preco_a { get; set; }
    public string codigo { get; set; }
    public string codigo1 { get; set; }
    public string descricao1 { get; set; }
}
```

ListBox:

```
<ListBox Name="List1" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" Margin="0,85,0,0" >
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="242" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="128" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <StackPanel Hold="addToList2" Margin="0,0,-62,17" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
                    <StackPanel.Background>
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF858585" Opacity="0.5"/>
                    </StackPanel.Background>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="NameTxt" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding descricao}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="20" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding valor_preco_a, StringFormat=N2}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="45,20,12,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding codigo}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="35" Margin="370,-50,12,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" Foreground="Blue"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="R$" Margin="15,48,158,17" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `foreach` is only checking the first value because of the `break` statements.  Furthermore the loop needs to check for the value matching, but you can only know if there is no match after the loop finishes.  So you need something like this.

```
bool found = false;
foreach(Fields fields in List1.Items)
{
    if (fields.codigo == insCodProduto.Text)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("this product exists!");
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}

if(!found)
{
    MessageBox.Show("this product not exists");
}
```

Also note that if you specify the type in the `foreach` it will do the casting for you.

Answer (score 2):

The answer of vallabha is completely correct. There is however another and perhaps easier solution to check if any item exists that contains what the user has typed. You can us the [**Enumerable.Any< TSource> Method**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb337697(v=vs.100).aspx).

In your code this would become:

```
var isInListBox = List1.Items.Cast<Fields>().Any(x => x.codigo == insCodProduto.Text);

if (isInListBox)
{
    MessageBox.Show("This product exists!");
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("This product doesn't exist.");
}
```

An advantage using this method is following (from MSDN):

> The enumeration of source is stopped as soon as the result can be determined.

Answer (score 1):

You could shorten your code using LINQ to check for the presence of any matches:

```
if (List1.Items.Cast<Fields>().Any(f => f.codigo == insCodProduto.Text))
    MessageBox.Show("this product exists!");
else
    MessageBox.Show("this product not exists");
```

It'll have the same effect as the code you're trying to achieve, since `Any()` stops looking through the collection (and returns `True`) when a match is found. Otherwise, it returns `False`.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using `break` in `foreach` loop after the first iteration it will break the `foreach` loop

Comment: Indeed, you probably meant to use `continue` though it's redundant in this case.

Comment: What the OP is probably trying to avoid is several "This product does not exist" messages before hitting a match.

Comment: @GrantWinney, exactly!